# 7-Zip and unzipping from command line

Tags: command-line, 7-zip

I am looking to use the command line 7-Zip to unzip a folder.

I have a file, say `example.zip` and want to unzip the contents of the file into a folder called `example`.

What are the commands I need to do this?

Comment: also FYI there is usually a distro package from their official repo. there is also the direct source which is from sourceforge (source and binary).

Answer (score 116, accepted):

`7z x example.zip -oexample`

```
Usage: 7z <command> [<switches>...] <archive_name> [<file_names>...]
       [<@listfiles...>]

<Commands>
...
  x: eXtract files with full paths
<Switches>
...
  -o{Directory}: set Output directory
```

---

Edit:

```
7z x *.zip -o*

extracts all *.zip archives to subfolders with names of these archives.
```

Strangely, I had to go to the full help file to find this example; it isn't shown for 7z /?.

Comment: good lord, i'm an idiot.  thanks much, appreciate the time to point out i should of paid more attention to the manual LOL, thanks again

Comment: actually, that isnt creating a folder based on name of file:

7za x -o"J:\IMC11N E\Batch\LehmanPoint\Reports" "993002005 S.20091228.zip"

Comment: `7z x` extracts with full paths; if you want to extract to current directory (ignore path info in the archive) use `7z e`.  i find both handy at different times.

Comment: that worked, thanks again for taking the time to point that out:


http://imagebin.ca/img/WhLSe0Sw.png

Comment: actually, it IS shown, if you type just 7z (minus the /?).

Comment: Got my vote just by mentioning `7z x *.zip -o*`

Comment: @Molly7244 in fact in the help you mention, there's no example with `-o*` using that wildcard in that place is not always supported by all programs.

Answer (score 19):

The syntax would be: `7z x <path to>\duane.zip -oc:\duane`

This will extract the content of the archive `duane.zip` to the folder `c:\duane` with full paths.

Note: There is NO space between the switch `-o` and the destination folder. If that folder does not exist, it will be created automatically.

Answer (score 6):

For [p7zip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P7zip):

```
7za e file.7z
```

Comment: perfect answer!!! +1 :)

Answer (score 3):

Recursively extract a single file, or a selective set of files from an archive into the current folder:

```
7za.exe e art.archive -ir!*Art.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

Without 7-zip powershell v3+ can extract a zip file:

```
Expand-Archive "Source" "Destination"
```

Comment: Powershell 5.1 can only extract .zips. e.g. for .gz "Expand-Archive : .gz is not a supported archive file format. .zip is the only supported archive file format."